# Python 3.4 Shutil Copytree

Tags: python-3.x

I have looked around for some help on this and can't seem to find the answer.

I am trying to copy a folder to a temp directory on windows using the following:

```
import os, shutil

shutil.copytree(os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '/Personalfiles', 'C:\\Temp\\newfolder')
```

The command works, but it is not creating a folder called `newfolder` instead it is just copying the `Personalfiles` folder to the C:\TEMP\ directory.

Comment: Better use `os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Personalfiles')` instead of manually forming the folder path.

Comment: Sorry but I dont get it, dont use the shutil.copytree instead use os.path.join and point to my new location?

Comment: No, instead of `os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '/Personalfiles'`, use `os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Personalfiles')`

Comment: Thank You I was able to solve my problem.